# Wave breaking in Burgers' equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

My understanding is that Burgers' equation is a prototype for wave breaking: Solution $u(x,t)$ stays bounded as its derivative $u_x(x,t)\to\infty$. I solved
$$u_t+uu_x=0,\,\,\, u(x,0)=-x,\,\,\, x\in[0,1],$$
and got
$$u(x,t)=-\frac{x}{1-t},\,\,\, u_x(x,t)=-\frac{1}{1-t}.$$
Surely $u_x(x,t)\to-\infty$ everywhere in $[0,1]$, but $u$ also does at any $x\in(0,1]$. I know $u$ along characteristics is constant, in this case it equals $-x$, and at the singularity time, $t^*=1$, all characteristics are converging to $x=0$, where $u$ is zero. So there is steepening happening in $u$ at $x=0$, but $u$ is not bounded for $t\in[0,t^*)$.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: From the example $u$ is not bounded for $t\in[0,1)$ and $x\in(0,1]$, thus what's happening here is not wave-breaking if the definition for such a phenomenon requires $u$ to remain bounded.

Comment: Still do not see a question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait for someone who knows about Burgers' equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Burgers equation is nonlinear, there can be infinitely many *solutions* in the sense that you are considering (just taking the derivatives and plugging them in the equation).

In order to select *the* solution to the equation, one has to be more restrictive on what can be considered a solution. In that sense, shocks are defined, mass conservation is imposed... and **rarefaction waves** appear. In your case, a rarefaction wave arises in $(x=1,t=0)$, opening to the left, which controls the height of the peak you are mentioning. In the graph below (characteristics in $x$ vs. $t$), you can see that, while the non-zero part of the initial data moves into a shock at $t=1$ (in red), a rarefaction wave appears in the *empty* space that it appears *behind* it.

[image]

I really like how this is explained in [Partial Differential Equations](https://books.google.es/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=evans+pde&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil2Z3A1JLLAhWCXRQKHZLNDxEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=evans%20pde&f=false) by Lawrence C. Evans, but you can find lots of notes about the topic in Google.

---

EDIT: In that book, you can find a [theorem](https://books.google.es/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&lpg=PP1&dq=evans%20pde&hl=es&pg=PA156#v=onepage&q&f=false) that describes the behavior of solutions to the Burgers equation in the whole spatial domain. It says that for bounded and summable initial data (hence, vanishing at $\pm\infty$), there exists $C>0$ such that $|u(x,t)|\le Ct^{-1/2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t>0$.

Moreover, the dynamics of the Burgers equation push all such initial data (whatever their shape is) towards a function called [*N-wave*](https://books.google.es/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&lpg=PP1&dq=evans%20pde&hl=es&pg=PA158#v=twopage&q&f=false), which IMHO is fascinating.

Comment: Thanks! I found that with $u_0(x)=x(1-x)$ and boundary conditions $u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$, the solution $u$ nos stays bounded on $0\leq x\leq1$ but its derivative goes to $-\infty$. But I am still wondering what types of initial conditions and/or boundary conditions will lead to that as opposed to both $u$ and $u_x$ diverging at some finite time.

Comment: I do not think I understood what is your doubt. Are you considering the whole spatial domain or just a bounded interval? Note that it is quite tricky to impose boundary conditions to this type of equations, since not all of them are _admissible_. On the other hand, if you consider the whole spatial domain, any compactly supported and bounded initial data remains bounded (with this bound going down to 0) and preserves the mass.

Comment: I was considering two settings, one with domain $[0,1]$, $u$ zero at the endpoints and $u(x,0)=x(1-x)$. The other on the same unit interval, but $u(x,0)=-x$ and no boundary conditions. For the first one, integrating the equation between 0 and 1 leads to the mean of $u$ being conserved. May be that and vanishing at the boundary  forces the solution to stay bounded (?).

Comment: Yes. Solutions to the Burgers equation with bounded initial data vanishing at the boundaries (or at $\pm\infty$) remain bounded.

Comment: I added a short paragraph at the end regarding this behavior. Please, accept the answer if you feel it fulfills your requirements.